# How can I select all elements with a class except one that has an ancestor with an id that matches a pattern?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an HTML document that has a lot of elements that have the style class `.ps-label`. I have a style I need to apply to all of them except one element. That element is found in a `div` that looks like this:

```
<div class="ps_box-edit psc_disabled psc_has_value g3form-hdr-formid" id="win5divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID">
    <div class="ps_box-label" id="win5divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_IDlbl">
        <span class="ps-label">Form ID</span>
    </div>
    <span class="ps_box-value" aria-disabled="true" id="G3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID">415</span>
</div>
```

There are two ids in the div that change. They are `#win5divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID` and `#win5divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_IDlbl`. The number will differ, based on a couple of different conditions. Because of this, I have to do pattern matching if I want to use this id.

How can I select all elements with the class `.ps-label` except for the one that is inside that `div`?

I have tried the following selector, but it isn't quite right.

```
.ps-label:not([id$="divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID"]) { }
```

It doesn't work because it doesn't refer to the span that has the label. It refers to the parent. How can I exclude the child of a div that has that specific id?

I've tried using the child selector `>` to get the descendent of the the div with that id, but my syntax must be wrong, because Chrome doesn't accept it as a valid selector:

```
.ps-label:not([id$="divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID"] > div > span) { }
```

What am I doing wrong with this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you make a typo? `.ps_box-label:not` should work..

Comment: Am there is no way to refer to the parent on CSS what you are doing is targeting the `ps-label` that is not with `id.....`

Comment: All elements had that structure ? `.ps_box-edit:not([id$="divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID"]) .ps-label` could work

Comment: I need to target all elements that have the class `.ps-label` except the one `span` that I have in the `div` above.

Comment: the easiest would be to make 2 rules one setting all the labels and the other overriding the exception. making sute the exception came after the other rule

Comment: "What am I doing wrong with this? Is this even possible?" :not() doesn't support complex selectors yet. Don't worry about it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add one rule that targets all the `.ps-label` then another that targets your exception

```css
.ps-label{
  color:red;
}

/* exception rule*/
#win5divG4FORM_WRK_G4FORM_IDlbl .ps-label {color:blue;}
```

```html
<div class="ps_box-edit psc_disabled psc_has_value g3form-hdr-formid" id="win5divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID">
  <div class="ps_box-label" id="win5divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_IDlbl">
    <span class="ps-label">Form ID</span>
  </div>
  <span class="ps_box-value" aria-disabled="true" id="G3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID">415</span>

  <div class="ps_box-label" id="win5divG4FORM_WRK_G4FORM_IDlbl">
    <span class="ps-label">Form ID</span>
  </div>
  <span class="ps_box-value" aria-disabled="true" id="G4FORM_WRK_G4FORM_ID">416</span>

  <div class="ps_box-label" id="win5divG5FORM_WRK_G5FORM_IDlbl">
    <span class="ps-label">Form ID</span>
  </div>
  <span class="ps_box-value" aria-disabled="true" id="G5FORM_WRK_G5FORM_ID">417</span>

</div>
```

another option could be to use this

```css
div.ps_box-label:not(#win5divG4FORM_WRK_G4FORM_IDlbl) + .ps_box-value{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="ps_box-edit psc_disabled psc_has_value g3form-hdr-formid" id="win5divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID">
  <div class="ps_box-label" id="win5divG3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_IDlbl">
    <span class="ps-label">Form ID</span>
  </div>
  <span class="ps_box-value" aria-disabled="true" id="G3FORM_WRK_G3FORM_ID">415</span>

  <div class="ps_box-label" id="win5divG4FORM_WRK_G4FORM_IDlbl">
    <span class="ps-label">Form ID</span>
  </div>
  <span class="ps_box-value" aria-disabled="true" id="G4FORM_WRK_G4FORM_ID">416</span>

  <div class="ps_box-label" id="win5divG5FORM_WRK_G5FORM_IDlbl">
    <span class="ps-label">Form ID</span>
  </div>
  <span class="ps_box-value" aria-disabled="true" id="G5FORM_WRK_G5FORM_ID">417</span>

</div>
```

Comment: This is way simpler than what I was trying to do. Thanks!